# 5 lists in data.frame get their mean, sd, removed outliers

Tags: r, list, dataframe, mean, lapply

I have a data.frame of **5 lists**

each list has 3 columns:

T_C is an indicator of TEST or CONTROL

id, T_C, SPEND

I know how to use lapply to get a mean of T or C, but how do you do that with multiple lists ?

```
dfList <- lapply(tableListBase, function(t) fetch(dbSendQuery(con, paste0("SELECT * FROM ",  t))))

dfList <- setNames(dfList, tableListBase).
```

??

For a single list I can do this ?

```
means <- tapply(NET_SPEND, TC_INDICATOR, mean)
```

I am learning :-)

My goal to get the mean(), sd() over these 5 lists T/C for now.

My ultimate goal is to identify: mean - 3 sd() and mean + 3 sd() and remove them from this 6 list set and create a new one, after removing outliers.

I know how to do this in a more manual formal not, more code of lines, but would like to learn how to employ more `FUN()` methods :- )

Comment: How did you get a data frame of lists? I genuinely didn't know you could do that. Why not a list of lists?

Comment: sorry, it looks like a data.frame in R, but it is just a list of those 6 queries

Comment: I think you probably have a list of data frames.

Comment: this is the most annoying interface, this whole web site, that I have ever seen in my life, super frustrating, by the way!

Comment: yes, you are probably right, it is a list of lists, 6 of them when I view it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few approaches you can take.  I've ordered them by which one I would most likely use myself:

```
# Make a list of 5 data frames.  I'll use `mtcars` for convenience, since 
# I don't have your data.

X <- lapply(1:5,
            function(i) mtcars[sample(1:nrow(mtcars),
                                      size = nrow(mtcars), 
                                      replace = TRUE), ])

library(dplyr)

# Bring all of the tables together and summarise
mapply(function(df, i){ df$tbl_id <- i; df},
       X,
       seq_along(X),
       SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(tbl_id, am) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg),
            sd = sd(mpg))

# Make a list of summaries
lapply(X,
       function(df) 
       {
         df %>%
           group_by(am) %>%
           summarise(mean = mean(mpg),
                     sd = sd(mpg))
       })


# Run tapply separately for the means and sds
mean_list <- 
  lapply(X,
         function(df)
         {
           tapply(df$mpg, df$am, mean)
         }
  )

sd_list <- 
  lapply(X,
         function(df)
         {
           tapply(df$mpg, df$am, sd)
         }
  )
```

Comment: will this work on my list of lists or does it have to be a data.frame ?

Comment: Benajmin - you are right, when I used  str(dfList), it said:  List of 6

Comment: I assumed you have a list of data frames, because that tends to be what you get back from `dbSendQuery`.  The last option would work for a list of lists.  If you have the option of making your lists data frames (all of the elements have the same length), I would recommend doing so.

Comment: I can't say that I understand, since I am learning, what is df, X ?

Comment: `X` is a list of data frames.  When I use an `apply` function on `X`, I am defining a local function to act on some object `df`.  I chose `df` to be short for "data frame".  So, in each apply function, `df` is a stand-in for an element of the `X` list.

Comment: > str(dfList)
List of 6
 $ Notes_Spend_201606:'data.frame': 64609 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Notes_Spend_201607:'data.frame': 100523 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Notes_Spend_201608:'data.frame': 62234 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Notes_Spend_201609:'data.frame': 57506 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Notes_Spend_201610:'data.frame': 59078 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Notes_Spend_201611:'data.frame': 55969 obs. of  3 variables:

Comment: I tried this, I think it calculated mean and sd over all the 6 lists ?

Comment: > mapply(function(df, i){ df$tbl_id <- i; df},
+        dfList,
+        seq_along(dfList),
+        SIMPLIFY = FALSE) %>%
+   bind_rows() %>%
+   group_by(TC_INDICATOR) %>%
+   summarise(mean = mean(NET_SPEND),
+             sd = sd(NET_SPEND))
      mean       sd
1 188.4113 696.2709

Comment: You need to use `group_by(tbl_id, TC_INDICATOR)`

Comment: same answer when I added that in.  Shouldn't it give me 6 answers for mean and 6 for sd ?

Comment: to me, this stackoverflow seems, like it was designed to rush everything through, I really dislike it, Google should not rank them highest, I really hate this web site.